# What does ctrl+. (period) do in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, office365

I particularly like the keyboard shortcuts used by OneNote (and a load of other applications), but specifically the ability to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>period</kbd>) to create a bulleted list.

So I created a shortcut in Word to do just that... except, it seems to be doing something else. It works to add the bullet points, but it also looks like it's doing some other long running process, because every time I do it, I get the loading icon. Unfortunately right now, I just did it on a 100+ page document, and it's been loading for about 5 minutes right now. When it first popped the loading icon, a status message came up on the bottom that said it was re-paginating.

I went to *File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Customize Keyboard Shortcuts* and I didn't immediately see anything else that had that shortcut assigned. I also couldn't find that shortcut in the list published from [Microsoft's list of Word Shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2).

**Question:** What else does the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> shortcut do? Or could it be caused by the bullet gallery action? It seems to get worse with the size of the document.

Answer (score 0):

What command did you choose to create this shortcut?

I try to create the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (Ctrl + period) for FormatBulletDefault, it seems work smoothly in my small document.

[image]

Besides, there are two existed shortcuts provided by Word to apply or remove bulleted list formatting, you may check whether these shortcut keys have same problem in big document.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: applies the predefined List Bullet style.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: removes bullets to apply normal style.

Comment: Interesting... I actually chose bullet gallery. Let me try remapping it to FormatBulletDefault.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help, but I'll keep it as your command, as it seems to be more accurate for what I was trying to achieve. I'm starting to think that it has to do with the fact that it's a shared document on OneDrive. I'll keep digging. Thanks for your help!